# Как повесить обработчик события на динамически созданный элемент li?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно повесить обработчик событий на ещё не созданный элемент `<i></i>` с классом `.delete` в `#tasks_container li`.
Получается что получить доступ к элементу мы сможем только после того как пользователь добавит новый task, поэтому нет смысла получать класс элемента сразу после загрузки страницы, он будет `undefined`.

```js
/**
 * Created by Den on 29.06.2017.
 */
var btnAdd          = document.getElementById('add'),
    textField       = document.getElementById('text_field'),
    tasksContainer  = document.getElementById('tasks_container'),
    dontShow        = true,
    btnDelete;

btnAdd.addEventListener('click', function() {
    toggle(textField);
});

textField.onkeydown = function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        addTask(textField.value);
        toggle(textField);
    }
};



function toggle(elem) {
    if (dontShow) {
        elem.style.display = 'block';
        dontShow = false;
    } else {
        elem.style.display = 'none';
        elem.value = '';
        dontShow = true;
    }
}

function addTask(task) {

    var parent  = tasksContainer;
    var newTask = document.createElement('li');
    newTask.classList.add('task');

    newTask.innerHTML = task + ' ' + setFormatDate() + '<i class="fa fa-trash delete" aria-hidden="true"></i>';
    parent.insertBefore(newTask, parent.children[0]);

    return function() {

        var successMsg = document.createElement('div');
        successMsg.classList.add('successMsg');
        successMsg.textContent = 'Add New Task';
        document.body.appendChild(successMsg);

        displayMsg(successMsg);

    }();

}

function displayMsg(div) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        div.style.opacity = 1;
        setTimeout(function(){
            div.style.opacity = 0;
        }, 2000)
    },10);
}


function setFormatDate() {

    var date = new Date(),
        num         = date.getDate(),
        month       = date.getMonth() + 1,
        year        = date.getFullYear(),
        hour        = date.getHours(),
        minute      = date.getMinutes(),
        formatDate;

    num   = String(num).length <= 1 ? '0' + num : num;
    month = String(month).length <= 1 ? '0' + month : month;
    formatDate = '<span>'+ num + '.' + month + '.' + year + ' <b>[' + hour + ':' + minute + ']' + '</b></span>';

    return formatDate;

}
```

```css
body {
    color: #757575;
    font-family: 'Consolas', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    background: #485563;
    /* fallback for old browsers */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to left, #485563, #29323c);
    /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient(to left, #485563, #29323c);
    /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
}

ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

ul li {
    list-style-type: none;
}

input, textarea {outline:none;}

h1 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 100;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
}

#main_app {
    margin: 6% auto;
    max-width: 860px;
    /*border: 1px solid red;*/
}

#head_app {
    text-align: center;
    background: #272727;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 8px 10px 5px;
    border-bottom: none;
}

#head_app li {
    display: inline-block;
}

#head_app li:last-child { float: right; }
#head_app li:last-child:hover { color: red; }

#add {
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 30px;
}

.input_block {
    width: 100%;
}

#text_field {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: none;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #333;
    color: #fff;
    border-top: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 15px 0px 15px 15px;
    font-size: 1em;
    display: none;
}

#tasks_container {
    color: white;
    font-weight: normal;
    width: 100%;
}

#tasks_container li:not(.end_tasks) {
    padding: 15px 0px 15px 15px;
    border-left: 5px solid #272727;
    border-right: 5px solid #272727;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #272727;
    font-size: .85em;
}

#tasks_container li span {
    margin-right: 1%;
    background: white;
    color: #000;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 3px 5px;
    float: left;
}

#tasks_container li.end_tasks {
    background-color: #272727;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
    height: 10px;
}

.task {
    background-color:  #F22613;
}

.fa {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 1%;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/*success msg*/
.successMsg {
    position: absolute;
    top: 1%;
    left: 90%;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    padding: 1%;
    text-align: center;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 1s;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>To Do js</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="libs/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div id="main_app">
        <header id="head_app">
            <ul>
                <li><h1>To-Do List</h1></li>
                <li><span id="add">+</span></li>
            </ul>
        </header>
        <input id="text_field" type="text" placeholder="INSERT A NEW TO-DO">

        <ul id="tasks_container">
            <li class="end_tasks"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <script src="scripts/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: почему бы не посмотреть в [ответе на твой предыдущий вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/687445/186999)?

Answer (score 1):

Можно воспользоваться делегированием событий и `.matches()`.

Покликайте на <kbd>+ element</kbd>, а потом на любой из добавленных в контейнер дивов.

```js
document.querySelector('button').onclick = function() {
  let element = document.createElement('div');
  
  document.querySelector('.container').appendChild(element);
};

document.querySelector('.container').onclick = function(e) {
  if (e.target.matches('.container div')) {
    let nodes = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.container div'))
    console.log('my index is', nodes.indexOf(e.target) );
  }
};
```

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 15px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.container div {
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.container div + div {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<button>+ element</button>

<div class=container></div>
```

Comment: Огромное вам спасибо, не знал что так можно делать.

Answer (score 0):

Повесьте обработчик на родительский элемент, в данном случае **#tasks_container**. Он будет ловить события на всплытии и обрабатывать их.

```
var taskContainer = document.querySelector("#tasks_container");

taskContainer.addEventListener("click", event => {
    if (event.target.classList.contains("delete")) {
        taskContainer.removeChild(event.target.parentElement)
    }
});
```